# Why was Skyfall delayed?

Tags: skyfall, james-bond

The James Bond franchise is an exceptionally long-lived one.  Every few years a new Bond film comes out, although there isn't a set schedule for when they do so.  However, looking at a chronology of [Bond film release years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_bond#Films) shows a general pattern of 2-3 years between releases if they're using the same actor as Bond.  When there's a change in actor, there are larger gaps.

However, the recent films had a 4 year gap between *Quantum of Solace* and *Skyfall*.  This seems particularly odd given that *Quantum of Solace* continued a reboot of the franchise started with *Casino Royale*, so a steady stream of frequent films is a good idea.  Indeed, between *Casino Royale* and *Quantum of Solace* there's only a 2 year gap.  This makes the 4 year gap between *Quantum* and *Skyfall* all the stranger.

What's the reason for the delay for making *Skyfall*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Production of Skyfall was delayed for several months in 2010-11 due to
>   the bankruptcy and delayed sale of studio Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM),
>   with the production being officially suspended on 19 April 2010.
>
> The press release from producers Barbara Broccoli and Michael G.
>   Wilson, for the film, then known as 'Bond 23', stated: "Due to the
>   continuing uncertainty surrounding the future of MGM and the failure
>   to close a sale of the studio, we have suspended development on 'Bond
>   23' indefinitely. We do not know when development will resume and do
>   not have a date for the release of 'Bond 23'". During this period,
>   some development and pre-production work continued on the film despite
>   the canceled financing, with the goal to have this Bond film in
>   theaters for the 50th Anniversary of the franchise. Production resumed
>   in January 2011.

See Production Notes in http://jamesbond.wikia.com/wiki/Skyfall

That's why it took time to release [Skyfall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1074638/). It also wriitten in Trivia of [Skyfall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1074638/trivia)

Comment: +1 Definite and correct answer to a question which seemed a bit vague at first. Man, I remember the times of the MGM bankruptcy, fearing *Bond 23* wouldn't ever come out or take so long that they might search another actor. I'm glad they managed to turn this chaos into the great experience *Skyfall* became.